# Migrate from MySQL to Postgres with unicode imperfections

Tags: mysql, postgresql, unicode, utf-8, migration

I have been tasked with migrating a database from MySQL to Postgres.  However, this database has unicode characters in places that are marked as `latin1`.  So, I'm worried about running something like

```
mysqldump --compatible=postgresql --default-character-set=utf8 -r databasename.mysql -u root databasename
```

because I'm not sure if we will run into strangeness from double-encoding unicode characters.  That is, encoding unicode characters into unicode

Does anyone know if I can do this and maintain the unicode as is?  Is there an idempotent unicode encoding algorithm that I should pipe this through?

Comment: Oh, you're in for some fun :S . If at all possible fix the bad data in-place. It's a similar problem to migrating an `SQL_ASCII` PostgreSQL database to utf-8; reading up on that might be informative. The tooling for it stinks because it's one of those problems you're ideally never supposed to get into in the first place.

Comment: Speaking of which, using `SQL_ASCII` in PostgreSQL will let you import your funky and invalid data unchanged... but your problems will just keep getting worse.  Much better to fix it up now.

Comment: If the dump contains **both** raw binary char data (such as cp1252) **and** utf8 - encoded (latin1), you'll need some heuristic fixing (or just stripping all unparseble char sequences) Please add (a part of) a hexdump of the dumpfile to your post.

Comment: what is a unicode character _marked as latin1_ ?

Comment: @DanielVérité: What I mean is that the sql tables are encoded in latin1, but there are unicode characters that have been pushed into them.  The dataabase needs to be able handle unicode, and as far as I understand, if I just change the collations on the tables, mysql will be unhappy because it tries to convert the unicode again (I could be wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Use can use my tool - it support unicode symbols
https://github.com/mihailShumilov/mysql2postgresql

Answer (score 0):

As Craig said above, you are in for some fun.  Not only are there no good tools for addressing this but the problems are likely beyond any one-size-fits-all tool.  The problem is that when you are crossing encodings, how to resolve this is beyond the information available in the data itself and involves understanding how you got there in the first place.

Now I am assuming your client apps currently handle the mangled data reasonably well.  If not, you have a lot more work on your hands.  If they do handle it, the best way to do this is to retrieve data, convert it into UTF8 *after processing it the way the client apps do* and then updating it.  This may take a while, and you should go through all potentially affected data.  That is really the limit of what can be automated.

If that is not sufficient, you are going to have to either manually correct (ick) or live with the bad data, but in that case, chances are the client apps are already living with bad data.